# How to convert mp4 Video to (.m3u8) playlist nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm creating a Video Listening web Application. In which users can watch videos. How can I convert mp4 video to .m3u8 playlist in node?

Comment: Use fluent ffmpeg

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of some converters or you cank also make use of ffmpeg, which is a little bit complicated. Here is the guide:
Step 1: Open up your terminal and install the package manager Homebrew for OS X. If you haven’t had it on your PC, you can run the following command to install it.

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Step 2: When finishing the installment of the Homebrew, run the following command codes to install the ffmpeg.

Brew install ffmpeg

Step 3: Now you can use the ffmpeg to convert the files. What you need to do is to enter the command line shown below and click the enter button for the system to respond to your request.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8

The interface of conversion process will look roughly like the graph below.

**Source:** https://enjoy-online-audio-video-movie.blogspot.com/2021/05/3-best-tools-for-converting-mp4-to-m3u8.html